# How to deserialize just one XML line on C#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I run a method on a service that returns just one line of XML on a string:

```
<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>
```

I was trying to deserialize this line this way:

```
var strXml = "<boolean xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'>true</boolean>";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(bool));
bool success = false;

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(strXml))
{
    success = (bool)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

But at the line

```
success = (bool)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

An exception is thrown:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 2)
```

There is any clue about what I can do? I'm quite new to XML serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just grab the value from the root node and try parsing it as a bool:

```
//load into XDocument
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<boolean xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">true</boolean>");
bool success = bool.Parse(doc.Root.Value); //true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [XElement.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse any individual element:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(strXml);
```

Sample:

```
string strXml = @"<boolean xmlns =""http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"">true</boolean>";
bool success = (bool)XElement.Parse(strXml);  // true
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GlDPXi)

Answer (score 0):

That XML looks like it was created with `DataContractSerializer`, so use that:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(bool));        

using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
{
    var success = (bool) serializer.ReadObject(xr);
}
```